# Picking up information from looped userform

Tags: vba, loops, userform

I'm using VBA in Excel and I'm stuck somewhere.

In my code I'm showing n times an userform with textboxes from which I would like to pick up the information each time the Userform is shown, in different cells not to lose the information.

I'm kind of helpless, any help would be welcomed.

This is the userform From which I would like to use the data:
[image: This is the userform From which I would like to use the data]

In order to show x times the userform and change its caption each times  I use the following code:

```vb
For i = 1 To ntrav - 1

AppInt.Caption = "Appuis intermédiaires n°" & i

AppInt.Show
```

Then in my loop where, before, I selected a cell from the sheet I'm interested in using the data from the textboxes:

```vb
If AppInt.CheckBox1Int = True Then

ActiveCell.Offset(i, 3).Value = "FX FY ZZ " & AppInt.TextBox1Int.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 3).Value = "FX FY FZ "

ActiveCell.Offset(i + 2, 3).Value = "FX FY ZZ " & AppInt.TextBox1Int.Value

ElseIf AppInt.CheckBox2Int = True Then

ActiveCell.Offset(i, 3).Value = "XX " & AppInt.TextBox3Int.Value & " FY ZZ " & AppInt.TextBox2Int.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 3).Value = "FX FY FZ "

ActiveCell.Offset(i + 2, 3).Value = "XX " & AppInt.TextBox3Int.Value & " FY ZZ " & AppInt.TextBox2Int.Value

End If

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select

Call Unload(AppInt)

Next i
```

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Not much to go on there.  Could you have a read of [mcve] please and share the code (not as an image, but copy and pasted) and images of the form.  I take it these are Excel forms?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems. Firstly you use `ActiveCell.Offset(i)`, meaning write the data (i) rows relative to the current selected cell. However you also

```
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
```

Which moves the selection on each step of the loop. This means each step of the loop you offset twice, once by moving the ActiveCell, once using i to look relative to this cell (and i keeps increasing)

So my advice is to save the ActiveCell to a variable at the top of your code then offset relative to that:

```
Dim firstRow As Range
Set firstRow = ActiveCell

'...
'everything is offset relative to firstRow
firstRow.Offset(i + 1, 3).Value = "FX FY FZ "
```

And remove the Select statements entirely.

The second problem is a bit more subtle and I'll wait till you have formatted your code correctly for that.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I did the changes ! but it's not solving the main issue I have...

Comment: @Lili ok well in that case, could you edit your question to explain what exactly is going wrong - does the code not run or throw an error? Does it run but do the wrong thing? Also please reformat the code as I described in the other comment to make it easier to read, I would do it for you but I can't do it very easily from mobile :)